# Obtain text between div tags within only certain span IDs with DOMdocument or SimpleDOM

Tags: php, dom

this is my code:-

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QR8A3T6sPzU");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$myNews = $xpath->query('//@id="watch7-views-info"')->item(0);
echo $myNews;
?>
```

how to get the all text between div tags within only certain span IDs...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use simpleHtmlDOM ([simpleHtmlDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)):

```
include 'simpledom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QR8A3T6sPzU');

// Find all divs with id watch7-views-info and echo their contents
foreach($html->find('div[id=watch7-views-info]') as $element) 
   echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

This would find all divs with the specific id, you mentioned something about spans, but you'll have to elaborate because I don't know what you mean.